# Using String Format from int to string double and keeping decimal C#

Tags: c#, decimal, string-formatting, number-formatting

I have the amount

```
  var Amount = 23454;
```

And I need to Format it like this: `234.54`

I searched for similar problems and tried this:

```
  String.Format("{0:0.00}", Amount / 100) // 234.00
  String.Format("{0:0.##}", Amount / 100) // 234
  (Amount / 100).ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")) // 234
```

but it removes decimals

Comment: `Amount` is `int` so you're doing integer division. Until you can see that intuitively, you should avoid using `var`. It's only worth the convenience if it doesn't hide what you need to see.

Comment: try `var Amount = 234.54m;`

The m suffix denotes a decimal.

Comment: `string.Format("{0:0.00}", Amount / 100m) // 234.54` <= one of the operands has to be a floating-point type, otherwise you're doing integer division. The easiest way to to this in your example is to either define `Amount` as a `float`, `double` or `decimal`, or put a `f`, `d`, or `m` after the `100` to indicate that *that* number is a floating-point type

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}", ((Decimal)Amount) / 100)
```

As mentioned before, you are working with an integer and not a decimal. You have to cast it before doing your logic

Comment: Or cast the `100` to a decimal: `string.Format("{0:0.##}", Amount / 100m)`

Comment: Thank you so much!